# How do I locate black rectangles in a grid and extract the binary code from that

Tags: image, image-processing, bit, omr

i'm working in a project to recognize a bit code from an image like this, where black rectangle represents 0 bit, and white (white space, not visible) 1 bit.

[image]

Somebody have any idea to process the image in order to extract this informations? My project is written in java, but any solution is accepted.

---

thanks all for support.
I'm not an expert in image processing, I try to apply Edge Detection using Canny Edge Detector Implementation, free java implementation find [here](http://www.tomgibara.com/computer-vision/canny-edge-detector). I used this complete image [http://img257.imageshack.us/img257/5323/colorimg.png], reduce it (scale factor = 0.4) to have fast processing and this is the result [http://img222.imageshack.us/img222/8255/colorimgout.png]. Now, how i can decode white rectangle with 0 bit value, and no rectangle with 1?
The image have 10 line X 16 columns. I don't use python, but i can try to convert it to Java.
Many thanks to support.

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm to find the 0-1 pattern or a way to access the image data in your program?

Answer (score 1):

This is recognising good old **OMR (optical mark recognition)**.

The solution varies depending on the quality and consistency of the data you get, so noise is important.

Using an image processing library will clearly help.

**Simple case: No skew in the image and no stretch or shrinkage**

Create a horizontal and vertical profile of the image. i.e. sum up values in all columns and all rows and store in arrays. for an image of MxN (width x height) you will have M cells in horizontal profile and N cells in vertical profile.

Use a thresholding to find out which cells are white (empty) and which are black. This assumes you will get at least a couple of entries in each row or column. So black cells will define a location of interest (where you will expect the marks).

Based on this, you can define in lozenges in the form and you get coordinates of lozenges (rectangles where you have marks) and then you just add up pixel values in each lozenge and based on the number, you can define if it has mark or not.

**Case 2: Skew (slant in the image)**

Use fourier (FFT) to find the slant value and then transform it.

**Case 3: Stretch or shrink**

Pretty much the same as 1 but noise is higher and reliability less.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Java, but in Python, you can use the imaging library to open the image. Then load the height and the widths, and segment the image into a grid accordingly, by Height/Rows and Width/Cols. Then, just look for black pixels in those regions, or whatever color PIL registers that black to be. This obviously relies on the grid like nature of the data.

Edit:

Doing Edge Detection may also be Fruitful. First apply an edge detection method like something from wikipedia. I have used the one found at archive.alwaysmovefast.com/basic-edge-detection-in-python.html. Then convert any grayscale value less than 180 (if you want the boxes darker just increase this value) into black and otherwise make it completely white. Then create bounding boxes, lines where the pixels are all white. If data isn't terribly skewed, then this should work pretty well, otherwise you may need to do more work. See here for the results: http://imm.io/2BLd

Edit2:

Denis, how large is your dataset and how large are the images? If you have thousands of these images, then it is not feasible to manually remove the borders (the red background and yellow bars). I think this is important to know before proceeding. Also, I think the prewitt edge detection may prove more useful in this case, since there appears to be less noise:

[image]

The previous method of segmenting may be applied, if you do preprocess to bin in the following manner, in which case you need only count the number of black or white pixels and threshold after some training samples.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Aliostad has made some good comments.

This is OMR and you will find it much easier to get good consistent results with a good image processing library.  www.leptonica.com is a free open source 'C' library that would be a very good place to start.  It could process the skew and thresholding tasks for you.  Thresholding to B/W would be a good start.

Another option would be IEvolution - http://www.hi-components.com/nievolution.asp for .NET.

To be successful you will need some type of reference / registration marks to allow for skew and stretch especially if you are using document scanning or capturing from a camera image.